# Codeigniter attachments with email not going properly or corrupted

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am sending an email with codeigniter, and in email attachment is also sending......
When i send an email on "Gmail" its working fine and attachment attached with that email is of correct size and opening properly, but when i send an email other than gmail account, attachment size is not correct, and its showing as corrupt..

Below is the code, can you please let me know how to resolve the issue:

```
            $this->load->library('email');
            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
            $this->email->from('eEmail address');
            $this->email->to("emailaddress"); 

            $message = "Message Here";
            $subjet = "Email with attachment";
            $this->email->subject($subjet);
            $this->email->message($message);

            $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
            $this->email->attach('resources/uploads/pdfs/'.strtoupper($prorder).".pdf");
            $send = $this->email->send();
```

Please please help me...

Comment: sending to another email should not affect the attachments, anyway have you tried with `cc` ?

Comment: but this things is happening... attachment not adding properly

Comment: For the `cc`'d users ?

Comment: there is no cc user... man there is some issue with the attachment sending...other is fine.. its fine in gmail.. but not in hotmail or yahoo

Comment: try adding $this->email->clear(TRUE);

Comment: @KeithAsilom added that as well but still same.. issue